# Issues with AWS lambda JAVA tutorial function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have issues which drives me crazy. I experimented with tutorial , tried to compile the simple lambda from tutorial on Baeldung for multiple days. Then gave up and used eclipse, still the same error.
That is my config on handler `com.example.lambda.demo.Hello::handleRequest`. Im afraid Im making the mistake here. the name of my lamda is MethodHandlerLambda . Im trying to upload the function through the console.

error output is :

```
START RequestId: 694f788a-4e42-4093-8014-b18c6c30ebf1 Version: $LATEST
Class not found: com.example.lambda.demo.Hello: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.lambda.demo.Hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

END RequestId: 694f788a-4e42-4093-8014-b18c6c30ebf1

Thank you in advance.

my Pom file is :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.lambda</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

my function is :

```
package com.example.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class Hello {

@Override
public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
  context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
  String output = "Hello, " + input + "!";
  return output;
}
}
```

Comment: Is that really code that compiles?  You've got a method in a method and no class definition.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant public class Hello {

@Override
public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
  context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
  String output = "Hello, " + input + "!";
  return output;
}
}

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the real code?

Comment: Done, sorry about it

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the correct [Java interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html#java-handler-interfaces) for your Lambda.  For the way you're doing it you'd have:

```
package com.example.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class Hello implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
       context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
       String output = "Hello, " + input + "!";
       return output;
    }
}
```

To test this, you can run it in the Lambda console with just a String input.

My `pom.xml` uses a bit newer packages too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.hotjoe.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>lambda-request-handler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: followed all the logic and still got  error. not sure how it is even possible. such a simple code. the project compiles just doesnt work on console, I even gave it full role permission to the lamda..  {
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: com.example.lambda.demo.Hello",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}